# Using .join in Scala to remove unnecessary lines from one database

Tags: scala

Lets say we have two Datasets:

```
Dataset 1:  
{id: 1234, ownerId: "george", marketplace: 1}  
{id: 2345, ownerId: "mike", marketplace: 1}  
{id: 3456, ownerId: "anish", marketplace: 1}  
{id: 4567, ownerId: "annie", marketplace: 1}  
{id: 5678, ownerId: "waker", marketplace: 2}  

Dataset 2:  
{id: 1234, marketplace: 1}  
{id: 2345, marketplace: 1}  
{id: 8888, marketplace: 1}  
{id: 9999, marketplace: 1}  
{id: 7777, marketplace: 1}
```

I want to be able to return a new dataset where it only contains

```
{id: 1234, ownerId: "george", marketplace: 1}  
{id: 2345, ownerId: "mike", marketplace: 1}
```

because the id is present in Dataset 1 and Dataset 2

I want to do this with .join because these files can have over 10k entries each and I feel that .isin() or other approaches can take too much unnecessary time

I know that in SQL it would look something like

```
FROM Dataset 1  
JOIN Dataset 2  
ON Dataset 1.id == Dataset 2.id
```

Could anyone help with this?

Comment: What lib are you looking to implement your logic using it? spark, slick, doobie? The APIs are different

Comment: i am using spark, my apologies

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, inner join is what you need, so having these 2 dataframes:

```
scala> df1.show
+----+-------+-----------+
|  id|ownerId|marketplace|
+----+-------+-----------+
|1234| george|          1|
|2345|   mike|          1|
|3456|  anish|          1|
|4567|  annie|          1|
|5678|  waker|          2|
+----+-------+-----------+


scala> df2.show
+----+-----------+
|  id|marketplace|
+----+-----------+
|1234|          1|
|2345|          1|
|9999|          1|
|8888|          1|
|7777|          1|
+----+-----------+
```

Perform an inner join on the id column:

```scala
scala> df1.join(
     |   df2, df1.col("id") === df2.col("id"), "inner"
     | ).select(df1.columns.map(columnName => df1.col(columnName)): _*).show

+----+-------+-----------+----+-----------+
|  id|ownerId|marketplace|  id|marketplace|
+----+-------+-----------+----+-----------+
|1234| george|          1|1234|          1|
|2345|   mike|          1|2345|          1|
+----+-------+-----------+----+-----------+
```